# Firebase data stream issue on Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, stream

I have a collection that persists user messages.

The stream from it keeps on trigger changes though no apparent changes occur to the database.

What's wrong with that?

I attached a stream on it as follows:

```
      ClassifiedAdMessage.getReceivedUnreadMessagesStream(toUserId: toUserId)
          .listen((event) {
        int unreadMessageCount = _unreadMessageCount;
        for (final change in event.docChanges) {
          switch (change.type) {
            case DocumentChangeType.added:
              unreadMessageCount++;
              //print("New message: ${change.doc.data()}");
              break;
            case DocumentChangeType.modified:
              debugPrint("Modified message: ${change.doc.data()}");
              break;
            case DocumentChangeType.removed:
              //print("Removed message: ${change.doc.data()}");
              unreadMessageCount--;
              break;
          }
        }

        if (mounted && _unreadMessageCount != unreadMessageCount) {
          setState(() {
            _unreadMessageCount = unreadMessageCount;
          });
        }
      });
```

Builds are triggered, increasing `_unreadMessageCount` continusouly.

The code I wrote to expose the stream:

```
  /// Get a stream on the unread messages for [toUserId] user.
  static Query<ClassifiedAdMessage> getReceivedUnreadMessagesQuery(
      {required String toUserId}) {
    // related to this add (ie. ownerId == toUserId)
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collectionName)
        .where("toUserId", isEqualTo: toUserId)
        .where("readDate", isNull: true)
        .withConverter<ClassifiedAdMessage>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) =>
              ClassifiedAdMessage.fromMap(snapshot.data()!),
          toFirestore: (message, _) => message.toMap(),
        );
  }

  static Stream<QuerySnapshot<ClassifiedAdMessage>>
      getReceivedUnreadMessagesStream({required String toUserId}) {
    return getReceivedUnreadMessagesQuery(toUserId: toUserId).snapshots();
  }
```